# SCSS variable value expected

Tags: css, sass

I have defined different variables in my scss file,
[Here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYtwH.png)

I try to change color to different color, and it always has error.

Even if I change back to the original variable, it still error.

[change to original variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaiu5.png)

But when I reopened Visual Studio Code, it won't show error

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXlZp.png)

How can i fix it?

Comment: As far as I know, this happens sometimes with VS Code. It is not an error, but VS Code marks it as one. If simply reloading/restarting it helps, there is no error.

Comment: I had the same issue and closed and reopened the editor. If anyone knows a permanent fix, I would appreciate it. Thank you for your time.