# Is there a way I can fix variable value expected in vs code?

Tags: css, sass

I want to change the theme colors but after the code the scss compiler is indicating an error related to variable value. I don't know how to fix this error.

This is the code i entered in the main.scss:

```
// Include custom variables default overrides here

$primary: #fd7e14;
$theme-colors: { 
    "primary": $primary
};

@import "./bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Then add additional custom code here
```

error:

> variable value expected scss(css-varvalueexpected)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749220/scss-variable-value-expected